# meaning of `__all__` inside Python class

Tags: python

I am aware of the use of `__all__` at module scope. However I came across the usage of `__all__` inside classes. This is done e.g. in the [Python standardlib](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/1863302d61a7a5dd8b8d345a00f0ee242c7c10bf/Lib/typing.py#L3328-L3333):

```py
class re(metaclass=_DeprecatedType):
    """Wrapper namespace for re type aliases."""

    __all__ = ['Pattern', 'Match']
    Pattern = Pattern
    Match = Match
```

What does `__all__` achieve in this context?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `typing` module does some unorthodox things to patch existing modules (like `re`). Basically, the built-in module `re` is being replaced with this class `re` defined using a custom metaclass that intercepts attribute lookups on the underlying object. `__all__` doesn't really have any special meaning to the *class* (it's just another class attribute), but it effectively becomes the `__all__` attribute of the `re` module. It's the metaclass's definition of `__getattribute__` that accomplishes this.

Comment: It's not actually replacing the standard `re` module. You might have gotten confused by the subsequent `sys.modules[re.__name__] = re`, but that's setting `sys.modules['typing.re']`, not `sys.modules['re']`. The actual `re` module is completely unaffected.